# Show applications "locks system"

Tags: keyboard, windows

My fifth time starting to use linux in the past 10 years and again I stumbled upon feature that I have no clue what it does and how to fix. All previous attempts to use ubuntu have stopped at similar "features".

Problem: I push windows key and everything becomes unusable. I think wasn't so before some update I made to Ubuntu some time ago. I cannot use browser but I can open/close software. I can click browser open and see the tab I was previously in but I cannot interact with it in any way after pushing windows key. I see the red cross for closing software on LEFT TOP of the screen. It is rather hard to explain and making a screenshot is rather hard since I dont know how to do and maybe its not even possible.

It's like software goes to some other screen that I cannot interact with.

How can I solve problem? Log out or restart computer. Windows key was working in this ubuntu previously!

I have no clue what happens to OS when I push the button. Please be so kind and help.

Comment: Basic criteria to have anyone be able to tell anything about your problems: 1) More detail required, 2) begin with telling which version of Ubuntu you're trying, 3) fill in as much details as possible; Amount of RAM, single OS on the boot media, any other boot media, other SPECIAL setup/features you have enabled, ...

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: More information:
Dell Latitude laptop
Single boot SSD no other OS's
RAM: 8 Gb
Special features: Touch screen
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

I have now concluded its not the windows button but the "Show Applications" that causes this problem.

Comment: More more information: I have installed some extension that moves clock and time to bottom of the screen. Can't remember which extension it was since this was 1,5 years ago...  (This is "secondary pc")

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was in some extensions I installed a long time ago. I reset Gnome to original settings and now it seems to be working. It seems though that now I have to modify appearance back to a usable state:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```